# Mongoose can't fetch the data , shows only empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have installed a local Mongodb Community Server and also tried with mongodb atlas.
I have wrote 2 traditional source file

model/model.js

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
const article = mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    author:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    desc:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Article",article);
```

index.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/ml").then( () => {
    console.log("Database is Connected Successful");
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
var Article = require('./model/model');
Article.find({},(err,data) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

In the mongodb server , there are 3 documents in one collection

```
db.article.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff6e22a516c5c65c73baef9"), "title" : "Data Science", "author" : "Anish Gupta", "desc" : "Data Science is core branch of Machine learning" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff6e22a516c5c65c73baefa"), "title" : "Mathematics", "author" : "Anish Gupta", "desc" : "Mathematics is core tools for Machine Learning" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff6e26b516c5c65c73baefb"), "title" : "Machine Learning", "author" : "Anish Gupta", "desc" : "Machine Learning is a great tools" }
```

But the problem is I cannot get the documents in the console log and even I have use the express.js to render an html file but there is only empty array.

The Output for the above/console.log is:

```
(node:2472) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2472) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Database is Connected Successful
[]
```

How to get down the document instead of empty array . Please help !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should pass some arguments
`useNewUrlParser: true`,`useUnifiedTopology: true`, `useCreateIndex: true`
to mongoose.connect() like this
It's works

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/stack", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Database is Connected Successful");
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
var Article = require("./services/AccessManager/article/model");
Article.find({}, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: I ran your code on local and every things is okey, check the mongo service on system and update your mongoos becuase your code is correct